# Insert Debezium records in another database

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, debezium

I have PostgreSQL database in Azure. In addition I have a Debezium connector pointing to this database. This connector produces data from some selected tables when new data are inserted into those tables.

Using Kafkacat, I can see the upsert records
[image]

Now I am looking a way where I can make a kafka consumer which will insert those records in another database while doing some slight modifications on each row.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Kafka Connect JDBC sink to write to another JDBC-compatible database.

Kafka Connect Transforms will allow you to do "slight modifications" on specific fields.